# How to generate a token to query a REST ArcGIS service?

Tags: c#, arcgis

I have a .NET application that needs to access a REST ArcGIS service. This service is a private one and requires token-based authentication to access the data within the service. Since I am new to ArcGIS, I have no knowledge of how to generate a token and use it in my .NET application.

Comment: First google result for "arcgis rest token": http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/acquiring-arcgis-tokens.htm

Comment: The url on that page does not open for me.

Comment: I want to generate a token based on the client id and client secret.

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple `http` requests , You can create a simple connection to follow the following.

First of all , you must know generate token url.
for example if your server `url` is http://myserver/arcgis/rest/services ....,

Your generate token `url` is: http://myserver/arcgis/tokens/generateToken.

The second operation is to prepare the model to generate a token, it is simply like below:

```
public class ArcgisTokenResponseModel
{

    public string token { get; set; }

    public string expires { get; set; }

}
```

And for reusable code , we may create a class that prepare querystring key values.
this class will simply look like the below code:

```
public class TokenModel
{

    public string f { get; set; }

    public string username { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }

    public string ip { get; set; }

    public int expiration { get; set; }

    public string client { get; set; }

    public TokenModel(string username, string password, string ip, int expiration, string f = "json")
    {
        this.expiration = expiration;
        this.f = f;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public string GetQueryStringParameter()
    {
        return "f=" + this.f + "&username=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&ip=" + this.ip + "&expiration=" + this.expiration;
    }



}
```

Then prepare a function that generate token from `ArcGis` server with username and password. This function may look like this:

```
    protected string GetToken(string generateTokenUrl,string username,string password)
    {
        try
        {
            string ipadress = _serverInformationHelper.GetIPAddress();
            int exp = 60;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                Model.Arcgis.TokenModel tokenModel = new Model.Arcgis.TokenModel(username, password, ipadress, exp);

                //token bilgisinin alınacağı server url'i
                string post = tokenModel.GetQueryStringParameter();
                WebClient clientToken = new WebClient();
                clientToken.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                string tokenResult = clientToken.UploadString(generateTokenUrl, post);
                ArcgisTokenResponseModel resultTokenModel = _seriliazer.Deserialize<ArcgisTokenResponseModel>(tokenResult);
                if (resultTokenModel != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultTokenModel.token))
                    return resultTokenModel.token;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

After all , whatever you want , you can use GetToken() function.

Comment: In order to authenticate to the service I need 2 tokens: one “token” I have and the other is the “access_token” which I think can be generated using the identity manager service. Only with the combination of both of them I will be able to access the service. I'm still unable to get the access token.

Comment: I think that you want use oauth2.0 on arcgis . if you want this you will follow https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/accessing-arcgis-online-services/ .

Answer (score 1):

Have a look how tokens are obtained in Esri's proxy:
https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/working-with-proxies/

And in particular:
https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/tree/master/DotNet
https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/blob/master/DotNet/proxy.ashx

Answer (score 1):

As @spiskula mentioned you could follow the method shown in https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/blob/master/DotNet/proxy.ashx, specifically the getNewTokenIfCredentialsAreSpecified method.

Here is a VERY simplistic example (pre .Net 4.5) of doing this same thing without the SDK. User will need to make this more robust with error handling, etc.

```
private string GetToken()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/");

        var postData = "client_id=yourclientid"; //required
        postData += "&client_secret=yourclientsecret"; //required
        postData += "&grant_type=client_credentials"; //required
        postData += "&expiration=120"; //optional, default
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        ESRITokenResponse eToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESRITokenResponse>(responseString);

        return eToken.access_token;
    }

public class ESRITokenResponse
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS pro addin,

1. Create token for ArcGIS Service.

```
    var url = "https://{baseUrl}/arcgis/tokens/generateToken";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    var postData = "f=JSON";
    postData += "&username={username}";
    postData += "&password={password}";
    postData += "&client=ip";
    postData += "&ip=" + GetLocalIP();
    postData += "&expiration=60";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var resString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    return (EsriToken)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(resString, typeof(EsriToken));
```

EsriToken is a class with 2 properties:

```
    public class EsriToken
    {
      public string token { get; set; }
      public string expire { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Set token in Application cookie for Service url:

```
    ProApp.SetCookie(new Uri("https://{baseUrl}/arcgis/services/"), "agstoken=" + token); // token is into EsriToken class...
```

3. Add the featureLayer as secured ArcGIS Service:

```
    await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
    {
      map = MapFactory.Instance.CreateMap(title, MapType.Map, MapViewingMode.Map, Basemap.ProjectDefault);
      ServiceConnectionProperties serviceConnectionProperties = new ServiceConnectionProperties(new Uri("https://{baseUrl}/arcgis/services/{YourServicePath}"));
      using (Geodatabase fs_db = new Geodatabase(serviceConnectionProperties))
      {
          IReadOnlyList<TableDefinition> definitions = fs_db.GetDefinitions<FeatureClassDefinition>();
          var dataset_name = "{YourDatasetNameHere}";
          var fc = fs_db.OpenDataset<FeatureClass>(dataset_name);
          try
          {
              var layer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateFeatureLayer(fc, map);
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              throw;
          }
      }
    });
    App.Panes.CreateMapPaneAsync(map);
```

Tadaa... Et voilà !!

Sorry for my English. I'm working on it...

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/accessing-arcgis-online-services/#using-rest for an overview. There are two options:

1. Easier: use the ArcGIS Runtime SDK: https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/use-arcgis-token-authentication.htm
2. Harder: post your own token request: https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/accessing-arcgis-online-services/#using-rest (no .NET samples, probably because you really should use ArcGIS Runtime)

Here's an ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET sample that uses a hardcoded login. The .NET page I linked above also has a sample that challenges the user for credentials.

```
try
{
    var opts = new GenerateTokenOptions();
    opts.TokenAuthenticationType = TokenAuthenticationType.ArcGISToken;

    // generate an ArcGIS token credential with a hard-coded user name and password
    // (if authentication fails, an ArcGISWebException will be thrown)
    var cred = await IdentityManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync(
                                 "http://serverapps10.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/", 
                                 "user1", 
                                 "pass.word1", 
                                 opts);

    // add the credential to the IdentityManager (will be included in all requests to this portal)
    IdentityManager.Current.AddCredential(cred);

    // load a layer based on a secured resource on the portal
    var layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(new Uri
                        ("http://serverapps10.esri.com/arcgis/rest/services/GulfLawrenceSecureUser1/MapServer"));
    await layer.InitializeAsync();

    // add the layer to the map and zoom to its extent
    this.MyMapView.Map.Layers.Add(layer);
    await this.MyMapView.SetViewAsync(layer.FullExtent);
}
catch (ArcGISWebException webExp)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to authenticate with portal: " + webExp.Message);
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to load secured layer: " + exp.Message);
}
```